# What does "return a in b" mean?

Tags: python

I want to understand how the `return` statement works. I am familiar with the `return` statement but not aware of the `return` **`in`** statement. Below is an example of a class method that uses it and I would like to know what it does.

```
def a(self, argv):
    some = self.fnc("Format Specifier")
    return argv in some
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: ...and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`value in values` means "`True` if `value` is in `values` otherwise `False`"

a simple example:

```
In [1]: "foo" in ("foo", "bar", "baz")
Out[1]: True

In [2]: "foo" in ("bar", "baz")
Out[2]: False
```

So in your case `return argv in some` means "return `True` if `argv` is in `some` otherwise return `False`"

Answer (score 4):

It means whether argv is an element of some(in Boolean value). some could be list, tuple, dict etc.

Answer (score 2):

It may be more clear if you know what happens in the background.  When you use `x in y`, that is a shortcut for `y.__contains__(x)`<sup>1</sup>.  When you define a class, you can define your own `__contains__` method that can actually return anything you want.  Usually, it returns either `True` or `False`.  Therefore, `argv in some` will be the result of `argv.__contains__(some)`: either `True` or `False`.  You then return that.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>If `y` does not have the `__contains__` method, it is converted to an iterator and each item in it is checked for equality with `x`.</sub>

Comment: This is not completely true. For `str` for instance, a `find` check is done, where iterating over `'abc'` would only result in `a`, `b`, `c`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: `'abc'.__contains__('ab')` -> `True`

Answer (score 0):

The `return` itself is of no importance here: you can interpret this as:

```
return (argv in some)
```

Now the in keyword means:

> The operators `in` and `not in` **test for collection membership**. `x in s` evaluates to `true` if `x` is a member of the collection `s`, and `false` otherwise. `x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`. The collection membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for many other object types to support membership tests without being a sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support membership testing.

Python uses a fallback mechanism where it will check whether `some` (in this case) supports one of the following methods:

First it checks whether `some` is a list or tuple:

> For the list and tuple types, `x in y` is `true` if and only if there exists an index `i` such that either `x is y[i]` or `x == y[i]` is `true`.

Next it checks whether both `argv` and `some` are strings:

> For the Unicode and `str`ing types, `x in y` is `true` if and only if `x` is a **substring** of `y`. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Note, `x and y` need not be the same type; consequently, `u'ab'` in `'abc'` will return `True`. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `""` in `"abc"` will return True.

Now every object that implements a `__contains__` method supports such `in` and `not` in test as is further described in the documentation:

> For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` is `true` if and only if `y.__contains__(x)` is `true`.

So besides implemented usages for dictionaries, tuples and lists, you can define your own `__contains__` method for arbitrary objects.

Another way to support this functionality is the following:

> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `true` if some value `z` with `x == z` is produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.

And finally:

> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `true` if and only if there is a **non-negative integer index** `i` such that `x == y[i]`, and all lower integer indices do not raise `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if in raised that exception).